# List to Data Frame with map_df is shifting rows

Tags: r, list, purrr, mapply

My data output is a list with nested lists of participant data.

- So one list will have Participant 1 through 5, for example

  - Within that list, Participant 1 will have 2 days of data and participant 2 may have 5 days of data (nested lists), etc.

```
DF = list(list(list(0.601705399641698)), list(list(1.0967226417789), 
                                         list(1.18794820947846), list(3.98557480186904)), list(list(
                                           0.995996328131446), list(0.564513260465204), list(1.31356753668681), 
                                           list(0.891872221784271)), list(list(0.649008813684839), list(
                                             1.0036615512612), list(NA_real_)), list(list(0.828273303379322)))
```

When I use map_df to combine these lists, it is shifting the rows like so:

```
xtest = map_df(DF, ~as.data.frame(.x), .null = NA)

# which comes out like this
structure(list(X0.601705399641698 = c(0.601705399641698, NA, 
                                      NA, NA, NA), X1.0967226417789 = c(NA, 1.0967226417789, NA, NA, 
                                                                        NA), X1.18794820947846 = c(NA, 1.18794820947846, NA, NA, NA), 
               X3.98557480186904 = c(NA, 3.98557480186904, NA, NA, NA), 
               X0.995996328131446 = c(NA, NA, 0.995996328131446, NA, NA), 
               X0.564513260465204 = c(NA, NA, 0.564513260465204, NA, NA), 
               X1.31356753668681 = c(NA, NA, 1.31356753668681, NA, NA), 
               X0.891872221784271 = c(NA, NA, 0.891872221784271, NA, NA), 
               X0.649008813684839 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.649008813684839, NA), 
               X1.0036615512612 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1.0036615512612, NA), NA_real_. = c(NA_real_, 
                                                                                    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X0.828273303379322 = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                    NA, NA, NA, 0.828273303379322)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

  X0.601705399641698 X1.0967226417789 X1.18794820947846 X3.98557480186904 X0.995996328131446 X0.564513260465204 X1.31356753668681 X0.891872221784271
1          0.6017054               NA                NA                NA                 NA                 NA                NA                 NA
2                 NA         1.096723          1.187948          3.985575                 NA                 NA                NA                 NA
3                 NA               NA                NA                NA          0.9959963          0.5645133          1.313568          0.8918722
4                 NA               NA                NA                NA                 NA                 NA                NA                 NA
5                 NA               NA                NA                NA                 NA                 NA                NA                 NA
  X0.649008813684839 X1.0036615512612 NA_real_. X0.828273303379322
1                 NA               NA        NA                 NA
2                 NA               NA        NA                 NA
3                 NA               NA        NA                 NA
4          0.6490088         1.003662        NA                 NA
5                 NA               NA        NA          0.8282733
```

It seems to be adding the data by columns, and shifting the new values instead of starting at column 1 row 2 for participant 2 and so on.

Is there a way to change the map_df data frame output to start at column 1 but keep the row corresponding to each participant?

Expected output:

```
                 1              2                 3                  4
1          0.6017054         NA              NA                NA # participant 1
2          1.096723          1.187948        3.985575          NA # participant 2
3          0.9959963         0.5645133       1.313568          0.8918722 # participant 3
4          0.6490088         1.003662        NA                NA # Participant 4
5          0.8282733         NA              NA                NA # Participant 5
```

Comment: Please include your *expected* output, i.e. the output you want, not just the output you don't want.

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Comment: Your sample data `list` contains no names. Where do the final column names `"Clm1"`, `"Clm2"`, `"Clm3"`, `"Clm4"` come from? In the `tidyverse`, reshaping entries from a name-less `list` will usually lead to some warnings/errors. Do elements from your actual data `list` have names?

Comment: The original list output is named [[1]] and so on per list/nested list. The map_df function seems to just name the column by the value within that list. The final column names "Clm1" etc, dont matter at this moment that was just me trying to clarify. They can be 1,2,3,4 as default or no names for the column and I can rename them later.

Comment: `[[1]]` and so on tells you that the elements are *unnamed*.

Comment: I have to say I struggle to understand your expected output. For example, what happened to elements 1-3 from `DF`? I can't see them anywhere in the expected output. Conversely, the first three rows don't seem to have matching entries in `DF`. The only entries that seem to match are elements 4-5 from `DF`.

Comment: I updated the DF expected output accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(DF, ~unlist(.x) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame())
#         V1        V2       V3        V4
#1 0.6017054        NA       NA        NA
#2 1.0967226 1.1879482 3.985575        NA
#3 0.9959963 0.5645133 1.313568 0.8918722
#4 0.6490088 1.0036616       NA        NA
#5 0.8282733        NA       NA        NA
```

Or the same using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(DF, function(x) data.table(t(unlist(x)))), fill = TRUE)
#          V1        V2       V3        V4
#1: 0.6017054        NA       NA        NA
#2: 1.0967226 1.1879482 3.985575        NA
#3: 0.9959963 0.5645133 1.313568 0.8918722
#4: 0.6490088 1.0036616       NA        NA
#5: 0.8282733        NA       NA        NA
```

Comment: This works for my subset data I posted of 5 participants; however, when I try to apply either method on 100 participant lists, I get an error: Error in t.default(unlist(x)) : argument is not a matrix. Update: I found a NULL value where a list should be, fixed by setting it to 0.